# Installing Coral Edge TPU software gives me "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycoral.adapters'" error

Tags: python, pip, tpu, google-coral

I am trying to install the Coral Edge TPU software on MacOS 11.5 by following these instructions:

https://coral.ai/docs/accelerator/get-started/#3-run-a-model-on-the-edge-tpu

But by the time I enter the following command into the console:

```
python3 examples/classify_image.py --model test_data/mobilenet_v2_1.0_224_inat_bird_quant_edgetpu.tflite --labels test_data/inat_bird_labels.txt --input test_data/parrot.jpg
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/fabrizio/Desktop/work/MagneticChessResearch/machine learning/Coral/edgetpu_runtime/coral/pycoral/examples/classify_image.py", line 36, in <module>
    from pycoral.adapters import classify
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycoral.adapters'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of python3 is installed on your Mac ?

Comment: I have Python 3.9.5

Comment: As answered by someone below: The solution is to either build and install pycoral from source on your Mac using Python 3.9.x, or downgrade Python to 3.8.x and install pycoral again. Pycoral source is available at https://github.com/google-coral/pycoral

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same issue on Windows 10. If you are using Python 3.9.x, and used the command `pip3 install --extra-index-url https://google-coral.github.io/py-repo/ pycoral` to install pycoral, then you will be installing a very old version of pycoral which does not have `pycoral.adapters` module. I think this is because the pycoral repo currently (June 2021) does not have the package built for Python 3.9.x.

The solution is to either build and install pycoral from source on your Mac using Python 3.9.x, or downgrade Python to 3.8.x and install pycoral again.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I think that's the problem, I have Python 3.9.5. How can I install pycoral from source as you have suggested?

Comment: Follow the 'Compilation' instruction from the pycoral git repo: https://github.com/google-coral/pycoral. I didn't try this myself, as downgrading to python 3.8 is OK with me.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much! At the end it was easier to downgrade to Python 3.8 and I ended up using pipenv which made everything even easier. Thank you again very much!

Comment: @FabrizioFerrari, Too much time consuming, If I knew downgrade is ok. I definetely do Python downgrading. :)